# Realm object gets `invalidated` before write, only on first run

Tags: ios, swift, realm

This one hurts really bad!

I create an entity like `var job = Job()` and pass it along to a few view controllers which have a `var job: Job?` property, each view controller is a form which sets some of the properties on `job`, the final view has a submit button which sends the job through network and writes it `realm.write {}` etc.

Now, I get all sort of `Object has been deleted or invalidated.`, `RLMArray is no longer valid.` realm exceptions crashing the app before getting to the last view or even writing the entity, and this only happens on first run right after fresh installation! it works fine after the first crash. I spent all day debugging and couldn't figure out why this happens.

Has anyone had a similar experience / issue with realm?

Comment: Hrmm, that's really odd! I'm curious though, why is an `RLMArray is no longer valid` exception being thrown if you're only looking after a single Realm object? Are you able to track where that's occurring? Are you doing anything else with Realm elsewhere while you're creating/updating this `job` object?

Comment: yes, this is a complex app and unfortunately I've just found this issue since it only happens after fresh install. `job` object has many `attachments` and has one `user`, first view assigns user to the job, second view adds a location (which is another entity) and third view sets some String / Boolean values on `job` and adds `attachments`. So, on first time run, it crashes on the second view with `Object has been deleted or invalidated.`, the second time it gets to the third view, but if I add attachments I'd get `RLMArray is no longer valid` and the third time I run the app everything works!

Comment: just found that
`println(job.invalidated)` is false and `println(job.user!.invalidated)` is true right before crashing, so the user gets invalidated, which is still odd, and trying to get the user name on the next view crashes the app

Comment: Yep, that would make sense. If the `user` object becomes invalidated, calling any properties on it would throw an exception. Hmm, okay, it sounds like your issue might be happening elsewhere than the creation of the `job` object itself then. I'm not sure if we can debug that from an SO post though. Would you be willing to send your app's code to the folks at Realm to take a private look?

Comment: I think I've just found the culprit! there's a script on app's startup which updates users, it fetches users from server, then in one `realm.write` block it does both `realm.delete(realm.objects(User))` and `realm.add(users)` now the first time there are no users to remove, and the new users get invalidated instead... probably this is a bug in Realm

Comment: Aha! Nicely done! It sounds like you just need to make your initial logic a bit smarter so it doesn't try and delete an empty set of users. Hmm, I can't say for sure without looking at the code if it's a bug in Realm, but if you think it is, feel free to create a sample app and post it on Realm's GitHub page! :)

Comment: unfortunately my NDA doesn't allow me to send the source code to Realm folks... but I'll try to create the same situation on a blank app and will submit a bug report after I'm done with this project... thank you very much for your time @TiM :)

Comment: No worries! I'm happy we sorted it out! That would be excellent! Thank you! In the meantime, I've added an answer summarizing this discussion to ensure that this thread gets registered as actually having a solution. If you like it, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. :) Good luck with the development!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this question gets proper closure, I'll summarize the discussion we had in that thread here.

The problem wasn't that `job` itself wasn't becoming invalidated, but that `job` had a child Realm object property called `user` and THAT was becoming invalidated.

All of the users in the database were being cleared to make way for a new list downloaded from the server, and that transaction was the cause of this issue.

So, as a rule of thumb, I think the takeaway from this issue is to be careful with delete transactions, as they can have implicit influences over other objects that may be referencing the objects when deleted.